# Передача данных в фрагмент

Tags: java, android

Классика учит, что активность не должна напрямую взаимодействовать с методами и переменными фрагмента. Только через интерфейсы. При изучении данной темы обратил внимание, что передача данных из активности в фрагмент, осуществляемая через Bandle, ссылается непосредственно на поле фрагмента в активности. Насколько это соответствует учению?

```
@Override
public void interface1(String string) {

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Fragment2.KEY, string); //Fragment2.KEY - поле фрагмента
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer2, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: Это стандартный способ передачи аргументов. Можно сделать интерфейс в котором будут константы для ключей бандла.

Comment: Вы перепутали. Все наоборот. Фрагменты не должны знать ничего про активити, а активити все знает про фрагменты которые хостит.

Comment: Константный интерфейс - это антипатерн. Вместо него лучше использовать константный абстрактный класс или enum.

Comment: Чем абстрактный класс лучше интерфейса?, а enum раздувает apk.

Comment: Можете почитать книгу Effective Java, в которой этот антипаттерн рассматривается. Или вот соответствующий вопрос с enSO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659593/what-is-the-use-of-interface-constants

Comment: Да, скорее всего вы правы в данной ситуации. В проектах которых работаю использую MVP с интерфейсами для view, которые сами отвечаю за свое отображение, ключи находятся в интерфейсах этих view т.к интерфейс это контракт, который view обязана выполнять.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, суть того подхода, который вы прочитали в книжках, нацелен на защиту данных в полях объектов от очистки, которая может происходить в Андроиде при множестве обстоятельств. И любое значение, которое было инициализировано в объекте (Activity), не застрахованно от пропажи в момент, когда к нему обратятся из другого элемента приложения (Fragment). 
А в вашем примере задействован только static ключ-идентификатор, который никуда не денется, сколько бы приложение ни сворачивали-разворачивали